# Problems with installing Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, failed-installation

When I try to install tinter from the command line with the command > pip install tkinter < I get always the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tkinter <

The same result with >pip3 install tkinter< 
I'm using Python 3.6 on Mac OS10.13.3

Any solutions? Thank you!

Comment: you cannot install tkinter with pip. You need to install a version of python that comes with tkinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter is a standard module in python. Try `python -m tkinter` to check if Tkinter already in your python :)
Tkinter constants tcl and tk, you can find your fit package [there](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).